# RCP: No progress dialog when starting a Job

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jobs, e4

When I start a Job I get the `NullProgressMonitor` by default instead of a progress dialog. How do I change this behavior?

#### Problem

According to this [article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Concurrency/jobs-api.html) under "Providing Feedback about Jobs" the only thing you need to set is `job.setUser(true);` to get a progress dialog.
But this does not work for me.

To reproduce the problem I created a new Eclipse4 project with sample content and modified the created AboutHandler:

```
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.*;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.*;
import org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class AboutHandler
{
  @Execute
  public void execute(Shell shell)
  {
    Job j = new YourThread(10);
    j.setUser(true);
    j.schedule();
  }

  private static class YourThread extends Job
  {
    private int workload;

    public YourThread(int workload)
    {
      super("Test");
      this.workload = workload;
    }

    @Override
    public IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor)
   {
      // Tell the user what you are doing
      monitor.beginTask("Copying files", workload);

      // Do your work
      for (int i = 0; i < workload; i++)
      {
        // Optionally add subtasks
        monitor.subTask("Copying file " + (i + 1) + " of " + workload + "...");
        System.out.println("Copying file " + (i + 1) + " of " + workload + "...");

       try
        {
          Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Tell the monitor that you successfully finished one item of
        // "workload"-many
        monitor.worked(1);

        // Check if the user pressed "cancel"
        if (monitor.isCanceled())
        {
         monitor.done();
          return Status.CANCEL_STATUS;
        }
      }

      // You are done
      monitor.done();
      return Status.OK_STATUS;
    }
  }
}
```

When I press the About-menuitem the only thing I see is the println() and in the debugger I see that `monitor` is a `NullProgressMonitor`.

Is this the default behavior? And how do I change it?

#### Solution

I wrote my own `IProgressMonitor` as greg-449 suggested. I found out that the jFace [`ProgressMonitorDialog`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fdialogs%2FProgressMonitorDialog.html) contains a `IProgressMonitor` and was a good reference for me.

Comment: How do you know that you get a `NullProgressMonitor`?

Comment: I started a debug session and set a breakpoint inside Job.run(). When I then hover over `monitor` it is listed as a `NullProgressMonitor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an e4 application it is your responsibility to provide a progress provider for the Job system using:

```
Job.getJobManager().setProgressProvider(provider);
```

where 'provider' is a class extending `ProgressProvider`. The provider returns the progress monitor to be used by the job.

[This article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJobs/article.html) has some information about the progress provider.

Comment: Is there a default ProgressProvider? I only have found ProgressManager but it is in an internal package, so I should probably not use that one.

Comment: No there is no default. You can't use the ProgressManager in 'org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress' because 'org.eclipse.ui' code doesn't work in e4.

Comment: I was not aware of that. What a pity that there is no default.

Comment: Yes, it took me some time to work out what was going on when I first ran in to this.

Comment: I am glad that I am not the only one.